# Querying for an array object in Postgres jsonb column

Tags: arrays, postgresql, psql, jsonb, postgres-9.6

I have a Postgres table with 2 columns "nodes" & "timestamp".The "nodes" column is of type jsonb & is an array of objects of the following format:

```
[
    {
        "addr": {},
        "node_number": "1",
        "primary": false
    },
    {
        "addr": {},
        "node_number": "2",
        "primary": true
    },
]
```

I want to find the object in this array that has `"primary":true` in the most recent row. If the above was the latest row, the result should be:

```
{
    "addr": { },
    "node_number": "2",
    "primary": true
}
```

I have tried:

```
SELECT(nodes -> 0) FROM table WHERE nodes @> '[{"primary": true}]'
order by timestamp desc
limit 1;
```

which gives the object at index 0 in the array not the desired object that has `"primary": true`.

How can I implement the query ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`jsonb_array_elements()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html) in a lateral join:

```
select elem
from my_table 
cross join jsonb_array_elements(nodes) as elem
where (elem->>'primary')::boolean

                       elem                        
---------------------------------------------------
 {"addr": {}, "primary": true, "node_number": "2"}
(1 row)
```

Comment: I cant upvote yet but this answer works - so thanks!